# Will I get in trouble for changing table and column names from upper to camelcase with JPA?

Tags: jpa

The column and table names that JPA providers create when you're not using `@Column` tags and the like, are always capitalized. I think the JPA spec even says they should. But is there a specific technical reason, like backends that are case insensitive?

In other words, will my habit of always setting camelcased names with the `name` argument to the `@Column` annotation turn around and bite me one day?

(Note that I appreciate convention over configuration, but sometimes I just want to have my way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having underscore-separated names for database objects is a bit of a historical habit, mainly because database systems are often case-insensitive. In this situation, having a table name where the words all run together is rather unreadable (e.g. MYLONGTABLENAMEISNTVERYREADABLE). Using underscores is just a naming convention to make things easier to read, just like camel case is.

If you move from underscore-separated to camel case, you'll be OK, since JPA implementations are designed to work with case-sensitive as well as case-insensitive databases.

Comment: By "are designed to work", do you mean, they'll automagically work around case.insensitive backends when I use names that require case-sensitivity to distinguish tables? Not that I ever had table names that were identical in all but letter case - I'd find that too confusing for humans anyway.

Comment: I mean that JPA implementations (e.g. Hibernate) have "dialects" for each database system, and will behave accordingly. If you have two names identical but for case, the dialects should complain.

Answer (score 0):

If the operating system where your database is running is case-sensitive, then the casing of table names must be correct.

In Linux, the following refer to different columns:

```
@Column(name="MY_TABLE") 
@Column(name="my_table")
```

Comment: At least for MySQL that is not true: table names ARE case sensitive, but column names ARE NOT.

Comment: Could you back this with some reference? I doubt that this is really who any of this works